# To pass two time for the same place. Logic question

Tags: logic

Let be the proposition:

```
"To visit two times the same place is forbidden".
```

It is forbidden to visit the same place three times?

A says:

```
 "No, because it is forbidden to visit the place two times".
```

B says:

```
"It is, because to visit the place three times you have necessarily to visit two times."
```

I think both answers are true.

Comment: I agree that it is personal opinion, because my first thought was, "It all depends on the circumstances." Who is doing the forbidding? Who or what is subjected to the rule? What is passing, what is it passing? A pendulum? I'm confused, and this seems more of a riddle than a logic problem.

Comment: I changed the verb "to pass". It is a pure logical question. The forbidding means "you just can't do it".

Comment: *B* is right (I'm assuming that you have in mind one visitor only). What makes you think that *A*'s answer survives *B*'s argument?

Comment: Thanks, now that part makes sense. But I don't see how it would be possible to visit a place three times without visiting it twice *first*. So I would choose B, not A. Also, I think it might depend on how "place" is defined.

Comment: It's a language thing, whether two times means *exactly* two times or *at least* two times. An ambiguity of natural language, not a genuine philosophical issue.

Comment: @Bread Say you have three dollars in your pocket. Do you have two dollars? No, you have three dollars. If I asked you if you have two dollars you'll say No, I have three dollars. But don't you have to have two dollars before you can have three dollars? Sure. But you don't have two dollars, you have three dollars! That's the game being played here. Whether "I have two dollars" means that you EVER had two dollars even though you have three dollars now? or whether you have exactly two dollars.

Comment: @user4894 You're correct that there's an ambiguity of natural language.  However, I don't think it matters in this case.  Clearly, on the "at least two" reading the answer is B.  But even on the "exactly two" reading, the argument in B still holds since visiting the place three times would require there to be a time (in between the second and third visits) at which you've visited exactly two, which is forbidden.  So the answer is B anyway.

Comment: If you look at A's statement there is the implication that A would allow the _temporary_ breaking of the rule, provided the place is visited again. B seem to apply the rule _at the time_ visiting occur. A and B therefore differ in the way _time_ is handled, but the "proposition" does not specify anything about Time... So A and B are voicing _opinions_, not anything logical.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the prohibition is directed at one individual visitor, *B* is right. The absence of indications of *temporary violation(s) being allowed* defeats *A*'s presumption that the prohibition refers only to the count of visits *as of* certain time/date.

For a person to visit the place thrice, that person necessarily has to violate the prohibition. Simply put, there is no such thing as a person's *double-visit* by which he can transition from having visited the place once to having visited it thrice.

By contrast, it is entirely feasible for a person to have one dollar and be paid two dollars with a two-dollar bill, whence he goes from having one dollar to three dollars without it being possible to identify an instant where he only had two dollars. Unlike the impossibility of *a person's double-visit*, there are two-dollar bills. Therefore, the [counter-example](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/61665/to-pass-two-time-for-the-same-place-logic-question/61679#comment170545_61665) formulated by @user4894 is mistaken.

In the dialogue of that counter-example ("*Do you have two dollars? No, you have three dollars*"), that response "*No, you have three dollars*" is actually answering the different question of "*How much [or how many dollars] do you have?*". But when a person has three dollars and is asked "*do you have one/two/three dollars?*", the correct answer in each case is *yes*. Similarly, when a person has visited the same place thrice and is asked "*did you visit the place once/twice/thrice?*", the correct answer is *yes*. And the affirmative in the questions with "*twice*" and "*thrice*" reflects that the prohibition has been violated.

The actual ambiguity in the OP's question is only whether:

- the place is prohibited to *be entered in* more than once (regardless of whether that is by the same visitor or different ones); or
- each individual visitor is prohibited to visit more than once.

*B*'s answer reflects a *conjecture* that the prohibition is by person (not by place), whereas *A*'s answer does not help to solve that ambiguity. Regardless, whatever conjecture(s) *A* and *B* may have are external and therefore irrelevant to what the actual question: the answer follows and never determines the question.